# Appending a 2d array in a 3d array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, append

Im stuck at a situation where I have used 3d arrays. I have following parent and child classes:

```
class Parent {
}
class Child: Parent {
}
```

Im able to create a 2d array of parent type and append it with 1d array of child type:

```
var arr2dParent:[[Parent]] = [[Parent]]()
var arr1dChild:[Child] = [Child]()
arr2dParent.append(arr1dChild)
```

The above code works fine.

But when I create a 3d array of parent type and append it with a 2d array of child type i get error:

```
var arr3dParent:[[[Parent]]] = [[[Parent]]]()
var arrChild2d:[[Child]] = [[Child]]()
arr3dParent.append(arrChild2d)
```

Im getting the following error:

```
Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '([[Child]])'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in types, look close:

```
arr3dParent.append(arrChild2d)
```

You are trying to append `[[Child]]` class to `[[[Parent]]]` array

```
var arrChild2d:[[Parent]] = [[Parent]]()
```

This works

Comment: katleta3000, But Child is a type of Parent. Moreover, it worked for the case of 2d parent array where 1d child array is appended.